# Navigation buttons in header xml

Tags: android, navigation, android-homebutton

I'm working on my first android app and have been trying to make a header consisting of three image buttons for back, home, and next. I was wondering if it's possible to make the header in a separate XML file, and then use **include** so that I may cut down on redundancy and reuse the header with multiple activities. I've been able to do this so that the navigation buttons display, but have not found a way to make the buttons navigate between activities. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intent to navigate across activities on button pressed. First, in the xml drag and drop a button. Then initialize this button in your activity. 
Eg.

`Button BackBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`

Once you have got reference to the button you can set onclick listener to this button and onclick of it, you can use to below code to navigate across activities.

```
Intent i =new Intent();
i.setClass(fromClass,ToClass.class);
startActivity(i);
```

I hope the above code would have helped.

Regarding the second part of the question, although you can define a seperate xml containing 3 buttons for navigation, you need to redefine its functionality in every activity you use them in. So instead i suggest you to create a sub-layout inside your current layout and in that add three buttons. From next activity onwards, you can copy paste that layout in your new xml.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll scrap what I was originally trying to do and go for the sub-layout idea.